# How to get test coverage for the frontend in razor on Visual studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, testing, razor, code-coverage, razor-pages

Do you know how to get test coverage for the frontend in razor on Visual Studio 2022? Right now, I'm experiencing ***Fine Code Coverage*** and ***JetBrains ReSharper 2023.1.1*** but none of them gives me the test coverage for the frontend. All they do is checking the coverage of the backend... Is there something I can do for getting what I want? I don't find anything.